# Output returning for every row

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

My goal is to return a statement like "Star wars is available: 11 on the shelf" but when I query the function, my output is returning that statement for every movie ID instead of just the one the function inputs. I know I'm overlooking something simple, but I just need my call to pull the statement for the movie ID provided. (Using SQL Developer)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION QTY_MSG_SF 
    (p_movieID mm_movie.movie_id %TYPE)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS  

lv_message_txt VARCHAR2(50);
lv_title_txt mm_movie.movie_title%TYPE;
lv_qty_num MM_MOVIE.MOVIE_QTY%TYPE;

BEGIN
    SELECT movie_title, movie_qty
    INTO lv_title_txt, lv_qty_num
    FROM mm_movie
    WHERE movie_id = p_movieID;


    IF (lv_qty_num > 0) THEN
        lv_message_txt := (lv_title_txt || ' is available: ' || lv_qty_num || ' on the shelf');
     ELSE
        lv_message_txt := (lv_title_txt || ' is  not available');
    END IF;
RETURN lv_message_txt;

END QTY_MSG_SF;
```

My call:

```
SELECT qty_msg_sf(2)
FROM mm_movie;
```

Comment: This function can only return one string. It is impossible for it to return multiple strings in one call - so the problem is probably in your calling code. Please update your question with the code you're using to call this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when I query the function, my output is returning that statement
>   for every movie ID instead of just the one the function inputs. I know
>   I'm overlooking something simple,

Your code is correct but it looks that probably you are not calling it correctly or all the movie id of the table are same. See below demo of your code which works as expected for me.

```
create  table mm_movie(movie_id number,movie_title varchar2(50), movie_qty number);
/
insert into mm_movie values (1,'WarDogs',11);
insert into mm_movie values (2,'Star War',19);
/
Select * from mm_movie;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION QTY_MSG_SF(p_movieID mm_movie.movie_id %TYPE)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

  lv_message_txt VARCHAR2(50);
  lv_title_txt   mm_movie.movie_title%TYPE;
  lv_qty_num     MM_MOVIE.MOVIE_QTY%TYPE;

BEGIN
  SELECT movie_title,
         movie_qty
  INTO   lv_title_txt,
         lv_qty_num
  FROM   mm_movie
  WHERE  movie_id = p_movieID;

  IF (lv_qty_num > 0)
  THEN
    lv_message_txt := (lv_title_txt || ' is available: ' || lv_qty_num ||
                      ' on the shelf');
  ELSE
    lv_message_txt := (lv_title_txt || ' is  not available');
  END IF;
  RETURN lv_message_txt;

END QTY_MSG_SF;
```

Execution

```
SQL>Select QTY_MSG_SF(2) from dual;

Col
---
Star War is available: 19 on the shelf

SQL>Select QTY_MSG_SF(1) from dual;

Col
---
WarDogs is available: 11 on the shelf
```

Comment: Thank you, I was calling this directly from the table mm_movie. instead of dual. Dual does work, although I'm not 100% sure why.

Comment: `I was calling this directly from the table mm_movie.` -- In this case you would had got the result as number of times as you have the rows in your table `mm_movie` but the results would had been same. Isn't it? We use `Dual` since we know its a `Dummy` table having 1 row and 1 column so we get result once.